# Cannot read property message of undefined. (At this.message)

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, discord.js

I'm trying to make a CommandHandler for my bot. So I'm using
**command.js**

```js
module.exports = class CommandHandler{
    constructor(message, args){
        this.message = message;
        this.args = args;
    }
    ping(){
        this.message.send("pong");
    }
}
```

And in index.js I'm just using it like

```js
const CommandHandler = require("./command");
/*
The Client on message and other initialization
then,
*/
let Command = new CommandHandler(message, args);
let Execute = Command["ping"];
Execute();
```

And I'm getting this error
**Cannot read 'messgae' of undefined**
And the debugger is pointing at `this.message.reply()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because the function lost the context. You can either call it on the `Command` instance via `Command.ping()` or bind the context in the following way.

```
let Execute = Command["ping"].bind(Command);
Execute();
```